# jQuery div to textarea wrap unwrap unwrapinner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jwysiwyg https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg but i want it to be applied to a div element instead of textarea. I don't think the plugin allow for using div. So i need to make div convert to textarea when clicked on before applying `.jwywiwig()` to it.

I want to make

```
<div style="width:300px;height:200px; background:red">testing</div>
```

Into this

```
<textarea style="width:300px;height:200px; background:red">testing</textarea>
```

How do i do this while maintaining the inline styling and html inside the div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better way to do this is to user [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)
That  way you don't need to worry about copying the text or styles. All you do is wrap and unwrap.

**To wrap do this**

```
$('#test').wrapInner('<textarea style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:transparent; border:0"/>');
```

*The inline styling is so the textarea takes full width and height on the parent div and also shows the background color of the parent div.*

**To unwrap the textarea do this**

```
$("#test").html($('#test textarea').val());
```

Comment: That's a great idea. Thanks, this works great for my purpose.

Comment: What's the process for going from a `textarea` to a `div`?

Comment: @jasper just user wrapInner() `$('#test').wrapInner('<textarea style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:transparent; border:0"/>');`

Comment: OK i got this part. I'm stuck at how to unwrap the `textarea`

Comment: That goes from the `div` to the `textarea` right? Which is slick +1. How do you go back to the `div` from the `textarea`. Meaning how do you `unWrapInner()` (since that isn't a real function)?

Comment: @jasper That's a good question. Here's the solution. `$('div textarea').contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 3; }).unwrap('textarea')`

Comment: It paid off after doing some research. nodeType is great

Comment: @Pinkie Does that save the changed value of the `textarea` when it `unwraps` (like if you add another word in the `textarea`)? Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bQTGE/4/

Comment: @jasper @pinkie Uh i see what you mean. This will work `var x = $('div').find('textarea').val().replace(/<textarea>/g,'').replace(/<\/textarea>/g,'');
$("div").html(x);`

Comment: @pinkie `nodeType` will not work. You need to use `val()` to get the new value of textarea

Comment: @jasper @pinkie. Here's another and much shorter way to unwrap the textarea `$("div").html($('div textarea').val());`

Comment: Im loving this wrapInner method very much.  iM having just 1 issue.  The div(s) have heading tags but when the contents is wrapped in a textarea the heading tags are somehow removed.  Can anyone explain why and a possible fix? hers a fiddle to show you http://jsfiddle.net/AHw8r/1/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do the following:

```
var textarea = $('<textarea/>');
textarea.attr('style', $(div).attr('style'));
textarea.text($(div).text());
$(div).replaceWith(textarea);
```

Creates a text area, copies over the CSS, and replaces the div.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `style` attribute of the `div` as well as it's text and then replace the `div` with a `textarea` that has it's `style` attribute and text set to that of the `div`:

```
    var $div  = $('div'),
        text  = $div.text(),
        style = $div.attr('style');
    $div.replaceWith('<textarea style="' + style + '">' + text + '</textarea>');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bQTGE/1/

Some documentation:

- `.text()`: http://api.jquery.com/text
- `.attr()`: http://api.jquery.com/attr
- `.replaceWith()`: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith

**UPDATE**

If you want to turn the `div` into a `textarea` when you click on it and then when you move away from the `textarea` it turns back into a `div`:

HTML --

```
<div style="width:300px;height:200px; background:red">testing</div>
```

JavaScript --

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', function () {
    var $div  = $(this);
    $div.replaceWith('<textarea style="' + $div.attr('style') + '">' + $div.text() + '</textarea>');
});

$(document).on('blur', 'textarea', function () {
    var $textarea = $(this);
    $textarea.replaceWith('<div style="' + $textarea.attr('style') + '">' + $textarea.val() + '</div>');
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bQTGE/3/

Comment: Thanks, how do we get it back to div when clicked outside. Do i have to redo the same code again in a reverse way.

Comment: @Pinkie Yeah, `$textarea = $('textarea'), text = $textarea.val(), style = $textarea.attr('style'); $textarea.replaceWith('<div style="' + style + '">' + text + '</div>');`

Comment: Thanks Jasper. Hussein's solution works better for my case without having to use all this code.